# Animation inside terminal with escape codes

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

Input file: [output of Tower of Hanoi in Brainfuck](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matslina/bfoptimization/master/progs/hanoi.b.out) (some codepoints may not render properly in your browser). The file basically uses [escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes) (more specifically `^[[m;nH`) to rewrite lines.

Running the command (you may need to do `sudo apt-get install pv` or equivalent)

```
cat hanoi.b.out |  pv -l -L 10 -q
```

gives output like

[image]

if the window size is big enough.

If not, the output looks like

[image]

where the image starts "scrolling down."

Naturally, this begs the question: why does this (mis-)behaviour happen when the window size is too small?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all of the output is cursor-addressing.  Some of it is line-feeds, which will (when the cursor happens to be on the bottom row) cause the terminal to scroll up.  Here's a visible rendering using [`unmap`](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:unmap) of the beginning of the output: look for the **`\n`** (newlines are "line-feeds");

```
\E[H
\E[2J
\E[2;27HTowers of Hanoi in Brainf*ck
\E[3;15HWritten by Clifford Wolf <http://www.clifford.at/bfcpu/>
\E[14;43H-----------------------------------
\E[24;23H-----------------------------------
\E[14;3H-----------------------------------
\E[13;3HxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
\E[12;5HxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
\E[11;7HxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
\E[10;9HxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
\E[9;11HxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
\E[8;13HxXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
\E[7;15HxXXXXXXXXXx
\E[6;17HxXXXXXx
\E[5;19HxXx
\E[5;19H   
\E[13;59HxXx
\n
\E[1;1H
\E[6;17H       
\E[23;37HxXXXXXx
\n
\E[1;1H
\E[13;59H   
\E[22;39HxXx
\n
\E[1;1H
\E[7;15H           
\E[13;55HxXXXXXXXXXx
```

When you use a smaller screen-size, the line-feeds that didn't cause scrolling are more likely to be on the bottom row, so you'll see it scroll up.

Comment: So the zero-point (for the later rewrite commands) shifts once the output has scrolled down?

Comment: yes - the chunks with `\E[` to `H` move the cursor to an absolute point on the screen, but the part of the screen you'd like to update has scrolled up.